# YouTube like TableView in iPad,Issue with Orientation

Tags: iphone

I Understand that custom cells are required to be created in order to acheive that.But the youtube tableview rearranges itself upon orientation.How can that be maintained considering you have to dequeue cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a a very simplistic implementation of a GridView. You'll likely need to customize it to your needs, but may be a good start. Just create it by called initWithFrame: and add your UIView objects to the children array. You may need to call setNeedsLayout after rotating, cannot remember.

```
//
//  GridView.h
//  Project
//
//  Created by Anthony Picciano on 7/28/10.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#define GRID_VIEW_DEFAULT_COLUMNS 1
#define GRID_VIEW_DEFAULT_HGAP 10.0f
#define GRID_VIEW_DEFAULT_VGAP 10.0f
#define GRID_VIEW_LAYOUT_NOTIFICATION @"layoutNotification"


@interface GridView : UIView {
    int columns;
    float hgap;
    float vgap;
}

@property (nonatomic) int columns;
@property (nonatomic) float hgap;
@property (nonatomic) float vgap;

@end


//
//  GridView.m
//  Project
//
//  Created by Anthony Picciano on 7/28/10.
//

#import "GridView.h"


@implementation GridView
@synthesize columns, hgap, vgap;


- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {
        columns = GRID_VIEW_DEFAULT_COLUMNS;
        hgap = GRID_VIEW_DEFAULT_HGAP;
        vgap = GRID_VIEW_DEFAULT_VGAP;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    float xpos = 0;
    float ypos = 0;
    float width = self.frame.size.width;
    float cellWidth = (width - (hgap * (columns - 1))) / columns;

    int currentColumn = 1; // columns number start at 1, not 0
    float maxRowHeight = 0.0f;

    for (UIView *child in self.subviews) {
        CGRect childFrame = CGRectMake(xpos, ypos, cellWidth, child.frame.size.height);
        child.frame = childFrame;

        if (child.frame.size.height > maxRowHeight) {
            maxRowHeight = child.frame.size.height;
        }

        if (currentColumn < columns) {
            currentColumn++;
            xpos += cellWidth + hgap;
        } else {
            currentColumn = 1;
            xpos = 0.0f;
            ypos += maxRowHeight + vgap;
            maxRowHeight = 0.0f;
        }
    }

    if (currentColumn == 1) {
        ypos -= vgap;
    } else {
        ypos += maxRowHeight;
    }

    CGRect aFrame = self.frame;
    aFrame.size = CGSizeMake(width, ypos);
    self.frame = aFrame;    

    NSNotification *notification = [NSNotification notificationWithName:GRID_VIEW_LAYOUT_NOTIFICATION object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:notification];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```